# Need serializer to serialize hyphens instead of underscores on get request

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, serialization

I am working on a project that is using a RestAPI. There are `@SWG\Parameter`s, which need to by hyphenated in the getter, but underscored for the serializer.

The issue I'm having is that these are used for a GET request. Due to get requests being in the URL, we want them to be hyphenated (like above, tariff name), so that it follows the conventions that we have elsewhere around the program.

The issue that we are having is that when using serialiser it does not serialize hyphenated fields correctly. I'm sure there is a setting or something I can change, or write a function that replaces them, but I'm not sure where or how I would do this.

Lastly, we only want this in this specific controller, not globally as it would adversely affect other parts of the program.

```
>@SWG\Parameter(
>>name="tariff-name",
>>
>>in="query",
```

Comment: Json standard is snake case for the seriliazer. I know that you can convert in symfony your values with a Converter. May this link will help you https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#camelcase-to-snake-case

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/configuration#extension-reference) it shows how to configure the separator

```
    jms_serializer:
        ...
        property_naming:
            id: ~
            separator:  _
            lower_case: true
            enable_cache: true
```